# Unix head/tail a percentage of lines to an output file

Tags: unix, line, percentage, tail, unix-head

I'm using unix to read through an excel file, sort by one column, and then I want a percentage (lets say the top 10%) of the sorted lines exported to a new .xls file. I have the code below which works fine but I need to do a `wc -l` prior to this line to get the "126", and then have to type it in (which is a hassle since I want to do successive filtering).

```
cat /Desktop/Results.xls | sort -n -k 3 | awk -F "[\t]" '{printf "%s\n",$0}' | head -$((126*1/10)) >./Results_0167_1.xls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `awk` to `head` the file itself:

```
sort -n -k 3 /Desktop/Results.xls| awk '{a[i++]=$0}END{for (j=1;j<=i/10;j++){printf "%s\n",a[j]}}' >./Results_0167_1.xls
```

The `awk` stores and counts ( `a[i++]=$0` ) the records piped by `sort`, after this process , in the `END` part it will print the recors till 10% is reached: `j<=i/10`